# Problem reallocating space to root after transferring 32GB NOOB to 64GB SD Card

Tags: sd-card, noobs, partition

I've seen some other threads out there but I can't seem to get any of the suggestions to work.  Maybe its because I can't seem to get GParted Live to run on my NUC.  I'm trying to resize the partitions with MiniTool Partition Wizard Free.  The problem is it will not let me resize the partition.  I tried to delete the root and recreate it with all the space, but I think that reformated the root partition and deleted my data.  How can I resize?  [image]

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange! Would it be possible to add some info about what exactly you tried, specific error messages and so on? Without more information is is not really possible to understand the problem and propose a solution.